# Magento 2.3.1 | Email Sending Not working

Tags: email, magento2.3.1

How can email sending works (contact- orders - forgot pswd ..) without using a third-party extension ( like Mageplaza_SMTP) ??

Should i make any sort of configuration in my local server ?

Ps : I did all the needed configs in Magento Admin Panel

Answer (score 0):

The server where Magento is installed should have a smtp server installed in order to have email sending working. There is no need for a 3rd party smtp server setup if you have postfix installed... 
Do you have full control over your server ?

Comment: Yes i have a full control

Comment: I checked the web server error log & it says  """"/usr/sbin/sendmail: not found"""

So should i use sendmail or postfix .. i have no one of them installed in my server ! *

Comment: if you have ssh & sudo access to your server, (Debian or Ubuntu : apr-get install postfix, CenOS or redhat : yum install postfix)